# How to console log on selected index?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the data from `data-egid`. How to do that?

```
<option class="dd" id="opt{{$z}}" value="{{$group_id}}" data-egid="1">{{$name}}</option>
// ...
function showOptions(s) {
  console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].value);
  console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].id);
  console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].data-egid); //this one is the problem
}
```

The value and id works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `getAttribute` function

```
function showOptions(s) {
  console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].value);
  console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].id);
  console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-egid")); //this on is the problem
}
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp

Comment: @Newbie Accept this as a answer if it helped. It will be useful for the people who will stuck on this sort of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Dataset API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to access `data-XXX` attributes.

```
console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].dataset.egid);
```

Answer (score 0):

That should `s[s.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-egid');`

Comment: @Newbie I don't see how it's returning undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].attributes['data-egid'].value);
```